# VaR calculation accuracy/comparison/effectiveness through different R packages

Tags: r, risk-management, value-at-risk, distribution, cvar

My question is what would be the better( in terms of estimation accuracy) method of VaR calculation among below two:, also any small code snippet will be great as a starting point for me.

1st method: I am trying to using a Generalized Pareto Distribution(GPD) there. I think R package POT or EVD might be of some help to fit my monthly historical return data to a GPD. Then using fExtremes package VaR might be calculated.

2nd Method : Another way is using PerformanceAnalytics package and trying calculate Modified Cornish-Fisher VaR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results depend on your distribution of losses.

If there is lot of departure from Normality, Cornish-Fisher VaR results will not be as accurate as GPD. But again to estimate block maxima effectively you need a large amount of data.

So it is difficult to say much without looking at the data.

Also, I would use the QRM package that accompanies the book, "Quantitative Risk Management".

Comment: is it the book "Quantitative Risk Management:
Concepts, Techniques, and Tools
Alexander J. McNeil, Rüdiger Frey, & Paul Embrechts"..?.btw how i can reach you ? my email: purnendumaity@gmail.com